# ¿ Como Establecer Propiedades de un Archivo desde Aplicacion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Desde mi aplicacion creo archivos perfectamente..., me gustaria saber si puedo establecer en Tipo de Archivo un Texto predeterminado donde marco en la imagen por ejemplo **SudokuEnCasa File JLL (.jll)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Esta](https://superuser.com/a/474153) respuesta puede ayudarte a lograrlo :)

Comment: Alli describe hacerlo desde el registro de Windows ..yo quiero hacerlo desde mi aplicacion ???

Comment: Busca la manera de acceder al registro de Windows desde tu aplicación...